# soapui tool run as an administrator in windows

Tags: testing

I ran into a problem I can't comprehend in regards to soapui tool. I have installed/ran sopaUI 4.5.1 from my windows 7 workstation. I imported xml file of all the test cases other developers have written/compiled. Not knowing I ran the soapui program as non-administrator, when I tried to run previously written test cases others have written failed. However if I run as administrator then it works. Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your current user does not have enough previlegies. So just run your tests as administrator.